# Java read from Stream as soon as content available

Tags: java, asynchronous, outputstream

I implemented a XML Sax parser over a dataset of about 4GB.
I process this dataset and I build several output objects.
Those object then must be sent as an Iterator to another service.
At the beginning I was thinking to finish the parsing, store the objects in a file and then retrieve them in the iterator by reading it.
I was wondering how can I do this asynchronously, that is in the `next()` method of the iterator wait until new content is available from the parser.
Thank you.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you wan't to make a pipe between your "download&parse" service and your other service and send it object as soon as it has been parsed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a classical producer/consumer program.

The easiest way to solve this kind of problem is to have the producer (i.e. the parser, running in its own thread), store read items to a BlockingQueue, and have the consuler (i.e. the service, running in its own thread) read items from this BlockingQueue.

To signal the end of the parsing, you can use a specific object and add it to the queue, or change the state (in a thread-safe way) of a shared object, that the consumer check before reading the next item from the queue.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Ok, let me see if I understand well, so when the Iterator is instanciated I make the thread within the parser starts to do his job and build those objects. In the thread I have a BlockingQueue where the content is stored. I will block the caller at hasNext() and wait if there is more content from the thread. Is that right? Any further advice?

Comment: Another question: Which implementation do you think it's the best?

Comment: No, what I suggest is to forget about your Iterator. Use a BlockingQueue, which, for the consumer, it a kind of blocking iterator: you call [take()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) on it, and it blocks until an item is available in the queue. For your use-case, an ArrayBlockingQueue is probably the best option: it makes sure to block the producer if too many items are in the queue, waiting to be processed, making sure you don't go out of memory.

Comment: Unfortunately that iterator is an interface for the consumer that I don't control, so I just `take()` the element from the BlockingQueue in the `hasNext()` and then I retrieve it in the `next()`, am I right? and what about the implementation? which is the best for my problem in your opinion?

Comment: You can have a blocking queue as suggested, and then implement an iterator to get its next element from the block queue. The rest will happen automatically.